# Accordion menu with picture icons & toggle icon

Tags: html, css, accordion, squarespace

I am looking to create an accordion menu that will have a different picture icon for each item on the left and then a toggle icon (like + or a chevron) on the right.

Style-wise, I'm aiming for this (https://codepen.io/kathykato/pen/MoZJom) except I essentially want to be able to add a different icon (it will be a designed icon) on the left of each item to indicate what the menu item is about.

I'm using SquareSpace, but plan to just input the code manually (SquareSpace doesn't have an accordion menu block/widget). I've tried playing around with various code for hours and have tried adapting/updating some examples, but this is my first time working with an accordion menu and I'm struggling.

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the code from the example above that I'm hoping to achieve but with a picture icon added to the left:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>

  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>Why is the moon sometimes out during the day?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>Why is the sky blue?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>Will we ever discover aliens?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>How much does the Earth weigh?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>How do airplanes stay up?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400');

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4d5974;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #373d51;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
  color: #7288a2;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.accordion a:hover,
.accordion a:hover::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a:hover::after {
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.active {
  color: #03b5d2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f218';
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #7288a2;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #7288a2;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion a.active::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f209';
  color: #03b5d2;
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion .content {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-height: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
}

.accordion .content p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.accordion .content.active {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
}
```

JS:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");

function toggleAccordion(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

Comment: Could you clarify whether you have the code working generally, but simply need help setting icons as mentioned? Or, do you not yet have the code working generally?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the following code (a somewhat stripped-down version of the example code you provided) via a code block accomplishes a few things:

1. It gets the module functioning, generally.
2. It puts all the code for the module in one place (the code block) for easier editing (as opposed to putting the HTML in a code block, the CSS in the header injection, and the Javascript in the footer code injection).
3. It adds an icon to the first item by adding a specific class in the HTML (`.accordion-link-info`) and some corresponding CSS within the `<style>` element.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a class="accordion-link-info">Why is the moon sometimes out during the day?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>Why is the sky blue?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>Will we ever discover aliens?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>How much does the Earth weigh?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <a>How do airplanes stay up?</a>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4rem;
    width: 48rem;
  }
  
  .accordion a {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
    color: #7288a2;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }
  
  .accordion a:hover,
  .accordion a:hover::after {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #03b5d2;
  }
  
  .accordion a:hover::after {
    border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
  }
  
  .accordion a.active {
    color: #03b5d2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #03b5d2;
  }
  
  .accordion a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  
  .accordion-link-info:before {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Info_icon.png");
  }
  
  .accordion a::after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #7288a2;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #7288a2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .accordion a.active::after {
    content: "-";
    color: #03b5d2;
    border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
  }
  
  .accordion .content {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  }
  
  .accordion .content p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  
  .accordion .content.active {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
    transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  }
</style>
<script>
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");

  function toggleAccordion() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
</script>
```

The CSS in the above snippet to pay particular attention to is this, which uses the `before` pseudo element and a specific image assigned for each link. In other words, you'd want to add a class to the HTML for each link (as I did for the first) and then set its background image accordingly in the CSS:

```
.accordion a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.accordion-link-info:before {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Info_icon.png");
}
```

Keep in mind that the module will behave poorly while previewing your site in edit-mode. You may need to keep a separate, non-logged-in browser open for testing.

Comment: That did the trick to add the icon on the right, and thanks for the tip about using a code block instead of adding everything in separate places (much easier!). 

It's fully functional, but the styling got a bit funky. I tried adjusting the width of the container, and that didn't make a difference.

![Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/P9EZfYP.png).

Comment: I suspect that has something to do with the other CSS on your site (assuming there is any) and or other factors specific to your site (as opposed to the code above). That's based on the fact that I did not see this in my own test within Squarespace. However, if you are able to provide a link to the page containing the code block (and the view-only password as necessary), further diagnosis can be performed.

Comment: Ah, the theme likely has CSS built-in. The page is http://www.willowstores.com/become-a-vip and the password to the page is workinprogress

Thank you!

Comment: Basically, that's due to the box-shadow that's been added, and the fact that the icons are absolutely-positioned. This could be fixed by refactoring the markup to use `inline-block` and static-positioned elements, but that is a separate question I believe. I would probably refactor the markup and CSS generally for a more mobile-friendly layout in any case. But this gets quite far outside the example code you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, darn. Do you have any example code that would be similar to what you're suggesting that I could work with? Or how would I go about changing the markup to use static positioned elements - and would that be mobile-friendly? I didn't mean to add the box-shadow,that must be happening from code that's elsewhere on the site.